# Telerik Radgrid Says There are 0 Records, but the Query Returns 185 Records?

Tags: asp.net, sql, telerik

I have an ASP.NET WebForms Application and am encountering one of the oddest problems in my nine months of coding in ASP.NET.

I added two new pages that both use Telerik Radgrids. Both Radgrids are identical, so I will focus on one of them in the hopes that solving one of the problems will solve the other.

**Html**

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="_radgrid" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSortCommand="_btnSearch_Click" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true"
    Skin="Office2007" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true"
    PageSize="50" OnNeedDataSource="_radgrid_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="_radgrid_OnItemDataBound"
    AllowMultiRowSelection="true">
    <MasterTableView AllowFilteringByColumn="true" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom">
        <CommandItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="_btnResolve" runat="server" Text="Resolve" OnClick="_btnResolve_Click"
                Visible="False" ClientIDMode="Inherit" />
        </CommandItemTemplate>
        <NoRecordsTemplate>
            No records to display.</NoRecordsTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" Visible="false" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Resolved" Visible="false" />
            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="CheckboxSelectColumn" FooterText="CheckBoxSelect footer"
                Visible="false" />
            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" AllowFiltering="false"
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/UpdatePage.aspx?Id={0}"
                Text="Update" UniqueName="UpdateHyperLink" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TradingPartnerName" HeaderText="Trading Partner Name" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocumentType" HeaderText="Transaction Set" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocumentID" HeaderText="Document ID" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
        <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
        protected void _radgrid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            Fill_radgrid();
        }

        private void Fill_radgrid(bool dataBind = false)
        {
            //Data Manager is a class that I built that makes all of the Database calls. It returns a DataSet
            _grdNegativeAck.DataSource = DataManager.GetRecords(_txtBoxId.Text, txtBoxDocumentType.Text, _chkBoxIncludeResolved.Checked, int.Parse(_ddlTradingPartner.SelectedValue));

            if (dataBind)
                _grdNegativeAck.DataBind();
        }

        protected void _radgrid_OnItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item is GridCommandItem)
            {
                //If the current user is authorized to resolve, show the Resolve button on the grid
                if (currentUser.IsAuthorized))
                {
                    GridCommandItem cmditem = (GridCommandItem)e.Item;
                    Button _btnResolve = (Button)cmditem.FindControl("_btnResolve");
                    _btnResolve.Visible = true;
                    _grdNegativeAck.MasterTableView.GetColumn("CheckboxSelectColumn").Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
            {
                //If the record is already resolved, do not show the checkbox on the side and color the record green
                GridDataItem GDItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
                if (GDItem["Resolved"].Text.ToUpper() == "TRUE")
                {
                    ((e.Item as GridDataItem)["CheckboxSelectColumn"].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Visible = false;
                    (e.Item as GridDataItem).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's where things get interesting. On my localhost, when using the same database, I get 0 records returned. I checked the DataSet that I'm binding to, and there is literally 0 rows. When I query the database, I get 185 records no problem. I double-checked the parameters I pass to the query, and they're the same. When I put this same code on the Test site, the page will get 184 records... when it should be matching exactly and get 185 records.

The other page doesn't get any records on either my localhost or my test site.

I'm really at my wit's end here. Anyone encounter a similar situation or have somewhere they can point me?

Comment: Can we have a look at the coding for '_radgrid_NeedDataSource'

Comment: I've added the Code Behind section. Let me know if this helps people better understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
_grdNegativeAck.DataSource = DataManager.GetRecords(_txtBoxId.Text, txtBoxDocumentType.Text _chkBoxIncludeResolved.Checked, int.Parse(_ddlTradingPartner.SelectedValue));
```

In the above line, you are missing a comma(,) after txtBoxDocumentType.Text.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I modified the code before I submitted the update to my question so I wouldn't display sensitive information. I must have missed that comma. I'll update the question now. The project compiles and runs successfully, but I still have this strange issue regarding the Telerik Radgrid and SQL.